# Message Warning: Preventing me to do anything else on the page: validateDOMNesting(...): <a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>

Tags: reactjs

When I open the console why I keep getting this error?

```
validateDOMNesting(…): <a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>
```

Also, whenever I include the `onChangeFirstName = {this.omnChangeFirstName}` to the input for first name for example I got the message that says that this handle will be ignored.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';

class SignUp extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);



        this.onChangeFirstName = this.onChangeFirstName.bind(this);
        this.onChangelastName = this.onChangelastName.bind(this);
        this.onChangePhoneNumber = this.onChangePhoneNumber.bind(this);
        this.onChangeEmailAddress = this.onChangeEmailAddress.bind(this);
        this.onChangeAddressUser = this.onChangeAddressUser.bind(this);
        this.onChangeCityUser = this.onChangeCityUser.bind(this);
        this.onChangeStateUser = this.onChangeStateUser.bind(this);
        this.onChangeZipCodeUser = this.onChangeZipCodeUser.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

        this.State = {
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            phoneNumber: '',
            emailAddress: '',
            addressUser: '',
            cityUser: '', 
            stateUser: '', 
            zipCodeUser: '', 
        }
    }

    onChangeFirstName(e){
        this.setState({
            firstName: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangelastName(e){
        this.setState({
            lastName: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangePhoneNumber(e){
        this.setState({
            phoneNumber: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangeEmailAddress(e){
        this.setState({
            emailAddress: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangeAddressUser(e){
        this.setState({
            addressUser: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangeCityUser(e){
        this.setState({
            cityUser: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangeStateUser(e){
        this.setState({
            stateUser: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangeZipCodeUser(e){
        this.setState({
            zipCodeUser: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onSubmit(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        console.log(`Form Submitted: `);
        console.log(`First Name: ${this.state.firstName}`);
        console.log(`Last Name: ${this.state.lastName}`);
        console.log(`Phone Number: ${this.state.phoneNumber}`);
        console.log(`Email Address: ${this.state.emailAddress}`);
        console.log(`Address: ${this.state.addressUser}`);
        console.log(`City: ${this.state.cityUser}`);
        console.log(`State: ${this.state.stateUser}`);
        console.log(`Zip code: ${this.state.zipCodeUser}`);


        this.setState = ({
            firstName: " ",
            lastName: " ",
            phoneNumber: " ",
            emailAddress: " ",
            addressUser: " ",
            cityUser: " ", 
            stateUser: " ", 
            zipCodeUser: " ", 
        })
    }



    render() 
    {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <br /><br />
                <form className="myLabel"> 
                    <div className="form-row">
                        <div className="form-goup col-md-4">
                            <label>First Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address"/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-goup col-md-4">
                            <label>Last Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name"/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-goup col-md-4">
                            <label>Phone Number</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number"/>
                        </div>
                    </div><br />
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Email Address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Address</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-row">
                        <div className="form-goup col-md-4">
                            <label>City</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City"/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-goup col-md-4">
                            <label>State</label>
                            <select className="form-control">
                            <option>Choose...</option>
                                <option>AL - Alabama</option>
                                <option>AK - Alaska</option>
                                <option>AZ - Arizona</option>
                                <option>AR - Arkansas</option>
                                <option>CA - California</option>
                                <option>CO - Colarado</option>
                                <option>CT - Connecticut</option>
                                <option>DE - Delaware</option>
                                <option>FL - Florida</option>
                                <option>GA - Georgia</option>
                                <option>HI - Hawaii</option>
                                <option>ID - Idaho</option>
                                <option>IL - Illinois</option>
                                <option>IN - Indiana</option>
                                <option>IA - Iowa</option>
                                <option>KS - Kansas</option>
                                <option>KY - Kentucky</option>
                                <option>LA - Louisiana</option>
                                <option>ME - Maine</option>
                                <option>MD - Maryland</option>
                                <option>MA - Massachusetts</option>
                                <option>MI - Michigan</option>
                                <option>MN - Minnesota</option>
                                <option>MS - Mississippi</option>
                                <option>MO - Missouri</option>
                                <option>MT - Montana</option>
                                <option>NE - Nebraska</option>
                                <option>NV - Nevada</option>
                                <option>NH - New Hampshire</option>
                                <option>NJ - New Jersey</option>
                                <option>NM - New Mexico</option>
                                <option>NY - New York</option>
                                <option>NC - North Carolina</option>
                                <option>ND - North Dakota</option>
                                <option>OH - Ohio</option>
                                <option>OK - Oklahoma</option>
                                <option>OR - Oregon</option>
                                <option>PA - Pennsylvania</option>
                                <option>RI - Rhode Island</option>
                                <option>SC - South Carolina</option>
                                <option>SD - South Dakota</option>
                                <option>TN - Tennessee</option>
                                <option>TX - Texas</option>
                                <option>UT - Utah</option>
                                <option>VT - Vermont</option>
                                <option>VA - Virginia</option>
                                <option>WA - Washington</option>
                                <option>WV - West Virginia</option>
                                <option>WI - Wisconsin</option>
                                <option>WY - Wyoming</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-goup col-md-4">
                            <label>Zip Code</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Zip Code"/>
                        </div>
                    </div><br />
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Sign up</button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <Link to="/residentPortal"><Nav.Link href="#link" className="myLink"><ins>Already have an account? Log in!</ins></Nav.Link></Link>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

        )

    }
}

export default SignUp;
```

Please provide help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I just removed every nested `<Link></Link>` I was using and it made the difference. Also `<Link> = <Nav.Link>` (Did not know).

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because a `Link` component renders an `<a>`and a `Nav.Link` also renders an `<a>`. You nested the second into the first which results in an `<a>` being rendered inside an `<a>` which is not valid HTML.

Your second issue is because an `<input>` element only has a prop `onChange` and not `onChangeFirstName`. You need to attach the handler to `onChange`. You can refactor your code to only have a single handler that uses the `name` property to update the correct state:

```
class SignUp extends Component {
    handleChange = e => this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <label>First Name</label>
                <input name="firstName" type="text" onChange={handleChange} />

                <label>Last Name</label>
                <input name="lastName" type="text" onChange={handleChange}/>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```